# Prevent Django form from hiding with invalid input

Tags: jquery, django

I craft my own lightboxy type event and it all works flawlessly in the event that the user submits good data. If there is a validation error triggered the form will submit, which refreshes the page, and my JS always hides the form on page reload.  So the data appears to the user to have been accepted when it's really just hidden with validation error's displayed.  How might I best prevent this from happening?

My HTML:

```
<div class='jobfrm'>
    <span class='closex' >&#10006;</span>
    <form method='POST' action = '' class='addjob'>{% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <input class = 'btn btn-default' type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'/>
    </form> 
</div>  
<div class='opacitydiv'>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.jobfrm {
    background-color: #E7D1FF;
    width: 400px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:9999;
    padding:15px;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.opacitydiv{
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index:9998;
    position:fixed;
    width:3920px;
    height:3080px;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
}

.closex{
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
    position:relative;
}
```

My JS:

```
// addjobs form js
(function(){
    var ajform=$('.jobfrm'),
        opa =$('.opacitydiv'),
        w = $(window).width()/2-ajform.outerWidth()/2,
        h = ($(window).height()-ajform.outerHeight())/2;
    opa.hide();
    ajform.hide();
    $('#addjob').on('click',function(){
        opa.show({
            'left':0,
            'top':0
        });
        ajform.show();
        ajform.animate({
            'left':w,
            'top':h
        });
    });
})();


//closes div and form
(function(){
    var ajform=$('.jobfrm'),
        opa = $('.opacitydiv'),
        close= $('.closex');
    opa.on('click',function(){
        opa.hide();
        ajform.hide();        
    });
    close.on('click',function(){
        opa.hide();
        ajform.hide();   
    });    
})();
```

PS: Feel free to comment about other unrelated aspects of my code if you see something that could be improved but isn't directly related to this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use another class in the form that is set if there are errors:

```
<div class='jobfrm{% if form.errors %} has_errors{% endif %}'>
```

and check that in your onload JS:

```
var ajform=$('.jobfrm')
if (!ajform.hasClass('has_errors')) {
    ajform.hide();
}
```

Comment: At first I thought this wasn't working because my form was displaying on screen but down lower on the page.  Took me a few minutes to figure it out.

Thanks, never knew you could do that with classes and django tags. Makes sense, but never would have thought of it